# How to delete (2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC) from filenames

Tags: powershell

I tried with Powershell as administrator with the command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match " ?\(\d\d\d\d_\d\d_\d\d \d\d_\d\d_\d\d UTC\)" } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace " ?\(\d\d\d\d_\d\d_\d\d \d\d_\d\d_\d\d UTC\)", ""}
```

I get many errors:

```
Get-ChildItem : L'accès au chemin d'accès 'C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup' est refusé.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match " ?\(\d\d\d\d_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\syst...es\WMI\RtBackup:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

What must I do?

Comment: I translated the question for you. But you should know that questions and answers must be in English, not French or any other languages. J'ai traduis la question. Mais vous devez savoir que les questions doivent ètre posées en Anglais, pas en Francais ou une autre langue.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the location is protected with Admin only access, or If you created the files or have the correct permissions to do what you are doing, then the administrator account is not needed.

***Never, ever do destructive code (Create/Modify/Update/Delete/Move/Rename) without
checking results first. You'll find yourself in a serious negative place.***   So, using -WhatIf or Confirm should be used in all cases.

[Powershell Best Practice #8: Use WhatIf and Confirm](http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-best-practice-8-use-whatif-and-confirm-parameters)

```
Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace " ?\(\d\d\d\d_\d\d_\d\d \d\d_\d\d_\d\d UTC\)", "") -WhatIf
```

As for the errors, you are over complicating this. It can be simplified to this:

```
# Test create some test files
0..2 | 
ForEach-Object {New-Item -Path "D:\Temp\SomeFileName$PSItem(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt" -WhatIf}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\SomeFileName0(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\SomeFileName1(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\SomeFileName2(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt".
#>

# Create the test files
0..2 | 
ForEach-Object {New-Item -Path "D:\Temp\SomeFileName$PSItem(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt"}
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                       
-a----         01-Dec-20     13:11              0 SomeFileName0(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt                                                                 
-a----         01-Dec-20     13:11              0 SomeFileName1(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt                                                                 
-a----         01-Dec-20     13:11              0 SomeFileName2(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt  
#>

# Get files in path
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC)*').FullName
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\SomeFileName0(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt
D:\Temp\SomeFileName1(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt
D:\Temp\SomeFileName2(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt
#>

# Delete the parens and all text between them
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*(*').FullName | 
ForEach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $PSItem -NewName $($PSItem -replace '\(.*\)','') -WhatIf}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\SomeFileName0(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt Destination: D:\Temp\SomeFileName0.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\SomeFileName1(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt Destination: D:\Temp\SomeFileName1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\SomeFileName2(2020_11_23 09_41_34 UTC).txt Destination: D:\Temp\SomeFileName2.txt".
#>
```

If you really need a regex for the date string, then you could do this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*(*').FullName | 
ForEach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $PSItem -NewName $($PSItem -replace '\(\d{4}|\d{2}.|_|UTC\)','') -WhatIf}
```

Remove the -WhatIf to have this complete the task and serialize the change.